# Set DisplayName in textfield problems Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity, c#, playfab

Folks. I'm trying to set the `DisplayName` default value directly from the API, the debug log correctly informs the username. But when I believe that it should fill the textfield, it generates an error. Could someone guide me to implement this function it would be very important for me I've been trying since yesterday, but without success.

Console error image --->
[image]

[image]
#region DisplayName

```
   public  void PlayerData(string playFabId)
    {
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetPlayerProfile(new GetPlayerProfileRequest()
        {
            PlayFabId = playFabId,
            ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints()
            {
                ShowDisplayName = true
            }
 
 
        },
  (result) =>
  {
 
 
      Debug.Log("The player's DisplayName profile data is: " + result.PlayerProfile.DisplayName);
      playerNameText.text = result.PlayerProfile.DisplayName;
 
 
  },
(error) =>
{
    Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
});
    }
 
 
    #endregion DisplayName
```

Full error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayFabController.<PlayerData>b__29_0 (PlayFab.ClientModels.GetPlayerProfileResult result) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayFabController.cs:232)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabHttp+<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1[TResult].<_MakeApiCall>b__1 () (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabHTTP.cs:215)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabUnityHttp.OnResponse (System.String response, PlayFab.Internal.CallRequestContainer reqContainer) (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabUnityHttp.cs:207)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
PlayFab.Internal.PlayFabUnityHttp:OnResponse(String, CallRequestContainer) (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabUnityHttp.cs:211)
PlayFab.Internal.<Post>d__12:MoveNext() (at Assets/PlayFabSDK/Shared/Internal/PlayFabHttp/PlayFabUnityHttp.cs:159)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, your playerNameText.Text is assigned somewhere?

Comment: First we need to narrow down which value is null. Add a few debug logs checking `playerNameText`, `result`, and `result.PlayerProfile`. The solution will depend on where this null is entering your data.

Comment: As I read it, the debug log is showing the username to the console correctly, just the text element does not work. But we do not see if or if not it is assigned

Comment: In the absence of a minimal complete verifiable example, I've linked this question to our general guidance on resolving null reference exceptions in Unity. You can edit your question to provide more details about your investigation into the problem and how to reproduce it, and users can vote to re-open it for answers.